# iOS: Dynamic Creation of UISegmentedControl within UIView

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am wanting to create a custom `UIView` class that will show a dynamic number of `UISegmentedControl` objects depending on some input. For example, if a client has 5 products in their cart, the `UIView` should generate 5 `UISegmentedControl` objects that I will then link with each item.

The problem I am having is getting this to work in a `UIView`. Here is what I have done so far. I am successfully able to create a `UISegmentedControl` object and display it programmatically within my main `UIViewController`. I don't get any display when adding it to my `UIView` class. Here is the implementation code for the `UIView` class:

```
#import "ajdSegmentView.h"

@implementation ajdSegmentView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
        NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Yes", @"No", nil];

        UISegmentedControl *button = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(35,44, 120,44);
        button.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
        button.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;

        [self addSubview:button];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

I created a new `UIView` object via Storyboard and placed it inside the `UIViewController` scene. I made sure to set the class from the generic `UIView` class to my new custom class. I added and outlet for the `UIView` in my `UIViewController` class. Here is the code inside the implementation of `UIViewController`:

```
#import "ajdViewController.h"

@interface ajdViewController ()

@end

@implementation ajdViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    self.segmentView = [[ajdSegmentView alloc] init];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

That's all I have tried. I have been searching through a lot of pages and trying to implement this without asking here, but I seem to be looking in the wrong places.

Comment: Did you verify in the debugger that `initWithFrame:` was getting called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're initializing your custom view using the `init` method, but your initialization for ajdSegmentView is in your `initWithFrame:` method (which in your case is not getting called).

So replace:

```
self.segmentView = [[ajdSegmentView alloc] init];
```

with:

```
// Change the frame to what you want
self.segmentView = [[ajdSegmentView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,40)];
```

Also don't forget to add your view to the view controller's view also.

```
[self.view addSubview:self.segmentView];
```

Unless this view is being created with interface builder, in which case you will need to override `initWithCoder:` in your ajdSegmentView class.

I'm not familiar with Storyboard though, so maybe I'm missing something, but in a standard scenario what I said above will solve your problem.

Comment: Overriding `initWithCoder:` did the trick. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

First you need to check ajdSegmentView is `UIVIew` or `UIViewController`. It is fine if it is `UIView`. If it is type of UIViewController then you need to add this line while adding Segment.

```
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

In place of:

```
[self addSubview:button];
```

And One more thing You forget to add this View to your main after allocating so You can declare like this:

```
objajdSegmentView = [[ajdSegmentView alloc] init];
[self.view addSubview:objajdSegmentView.view];
```

I have just added this thing. i got result like this way.[image]

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: I've already added the `UIView` to the `UIViewController` via Storyboard. I linked the `UIView` using an Outlet. Nothing shows on the UIView at this point.

Comment: If I choose to do everything programmatically it adds the view and buttong just fine. What I've done was created a new `ajdSegmentView` object and added it to the `UIViewController` using `[self.view addSubview:newSegmentView]`. It shows the button, but I am unable to interact with it.

Comment: You have to add this method: [segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(action:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];

Comment: You can add this method in ajdViewController class while initiating your segment.